# Can someone please translate this from Cantonese to English for me?

Tags: cantonese

My girlfriend wrote it and it's important to me. Thank you so much.

點解依個世界有啲咁幼稚嘅人
點解我唔好以靚啲瘦啲叻啲 有一技之長 點解我乜都做唔好 點解咁多個唔揀揀我 點解冇人中意我 點解我做幾多野都冇人欣賞 
其實我個人偏向中性某程度上係因為冇男嘅候我所以我索性乜都唔理 其實我唔係特登sad比人睇 只係有時唔知係邊度同埋唔知點抒發情緒好 
其實都係咁樣好多年 點解唔比我抖下 點解唔可以長眠點解仲要生存

Comment: Your gf wrote you something important and you're publishing it on the net for complete strangers to read? Why do you think it is OK?

Comment: No punctuation marks. This text is not meant to be read by anyone else but the author herself.  you two need to talk

Comment: Yeah that's definitely not content that should be floating on the 'Net...

Answer (score 2):

The last sentence seems to be the most important:

- "點解" -> why
- "唔" -> not
- "比" (should be "俾" here) -> allow
- "抖" -> rest
- "長眠" -> prolonged sleep ... or death
- "仲要" (should be "重" "要" here) -> 重=still, 要=need
- "生存" -> stay alive